# Get only the text with python regex

Tags: python, regex

How can I get

> The president of the United States
>   appoints the cabinet members,
>   appointments are subject to Senate
>   approval.

from

```
1. The president of the United States
appoints the cabinet members,

appointments are subject to Senate
approval.

(A) their

(B) with their
(C) because their
(D) but their
```

I start my pattern but it stop at the word 'States'. Also I try to put the
the first parenthesis of (A) as end of string but still not working

```
import re

regex = r'\d{1,}\.\s(\w.+)'
```

Comment: You don't show where you are creating the regex object; are you using the [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag?

Comment: Please post a [mre] including the actual search. BTW, isn't `{1,}` equivalent to `+`?

Comment: @0x5453 I think you're thinking of [`DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in python:

```
r'(?s)\A\d+\.\s+(.+?)(?=\n\()'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhZkQ2/1)

Here are regex details:

- `(?s)`: Enable single line mode in regex
- `\A`: Start of input
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `\.`: Match a `.`
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(.+?)`: Our matched text that is will have 1+ of any characters including line breaks, captured in group #1
- `(?=\n\()`: Lookahead to ensure that match has a line break and `(` ahead

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just to clarify why the advantage when you say to enable single line mode?

Comment: If you don't enable `single line mode` then `(.+?)` won't match newline

Comment: Excellent explanation